# Print all tabs on a webpage: based on given example on codepen.io

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to reproduce the example on the link below to print all nav tabs

Example:
[example:print-all-tabs-on-a-webpage](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWxvEo)

Link taken from a stackoverflow question:
[print-all-tabs-on-a-webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33261642/print-all-tabs-on-a-webpage)

But I am getting a page like this one:

[image]

Nav buttons are not functioning properly and the print button does not do anything.

I just added this to the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print-nav-tabs.css">
```

and

```
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
```

Otherwise, I have the exact same code as in the example. Why does it not work? What am I mising?

Answer (score 0):

I exported the zip of the code in https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWxvEo, and then I noticed that the css was not rendered well because this was missing:

```
 <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css'>

  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
```